# What token to use for the github api if I want everything publically available of an organisation

Tags: rest, authentication, http, github-api, bruno

I am so confused.
This is the only request of data I want, that works properly:

```
meta {
  name: Get an organization
  type: http
  seq: 1
}

get {
  url: {{host}}/orgs/propromo-software
  body: none
  auth: bearer
}

headers {
  X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28
  Accept: application/vnd.github+json
}

auth:bearer {
  token: {{GITHUB_API_TOKEN}}
}
```

Somehow this one returns an empty array (there are public projects in the organisation, I am the creator and the owner of the organisation and the project and the previous request works fine):

```
meta {
  name: List organization projects
  type: http
  seq: 1
}

get {
  url: {{host}}/orgs/propromo-software/projects
  body: none
  auth: bearer
}

headers {
  X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28
  Accept: application/vnd.github+json
}

auth:bearer {
  token: {{GITHUB_API_TOKEN}}
}
```

These two: `{{host}}/projects/1/collaborators`, `{{host}}/projects/1/columns` and some other ones return:

```bash
{
  "message": "Must have admin rights to Repository.",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/projects/cards#list-project-cards"
}
```

This is confusing, because as I said: "I am the creator of the organisation and everything in it".
After reading that, I added myself as collaborator to the repo. Still doesn't work.

What I tried: Fine-grained personal access tokens (using the organisation) and Personal access tokens (classic) (using my personal account, the one that I created the organisation with).

(I use bruno for the request testing)

The token type should be valid too according to https://docs.github.com/de/rest/authentication/authenticating-to-the-rest-api?apiVersion=2022-11-28:

Note: In most cases, you can use Authorization: Bearer or Authorization: token to pass a token. However, if you are passing a JSON web token (JWT), you must use Authorization: Bearer.

And Yes, I tried using curl too. Same results.
First I tried a token with read acces to almost everything and then I tried one that had every privilige possible.
I also authenticated with all the tokens i tried fetching data with (https://docs.github.com/en/rest/authentication/authenticating-to-the-rest-api?apiVersion=2022-11-28#basic-authentication).

If that is the problem...
After detecting several requests with invalid credentials within a short period, the API will temporarily reject all authentication attempts for that user (including ones with valid credentials) with a 403 Forbidden response. For more information, see "Rate limits for the REST API."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access everything publicly available to an organization through the GitHub API, the best approach is to use a Personal Access Token (PAT) with the appropriate scopes. From your question, you have already tried using both fine-grained personal access tokens and classic personal access tokens.

Still, make sure you have [`repo` and `admin:org` scopes](https://docs.github.com/en/apps/oauth-apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps) (start with a classic token, for testing).
Replace `{{GITHUB_API_TOKEN}}` in your request with the PAT you have created. Make sure you are using the correct [GitHub API version](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/about-the-rest-api/api-versions?apiVersion=2022-11-28) in your headers.

```
meta {
  name: List organization projects
  type: http
  seq: 1
}

get {
  url: {{host}}/orgs/propromo-software/projects
  body: none
  auth: bearer
}

headers {
  X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28
  Accept: application/vnd.github+json
}

auth:bearer {
  token: <Your Personal Access Token>
}
```

Consider [GitHub's rate limiting](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/using-the-rest-api/rate-limits-for-the-rest-api?apiVersion=2022-11-28), especially after several failed attempts. And make sure the projects you are trying to access are indeed public.

---

But, regarding `/projects`, it does not seems to be exposed through REST API, only GraphQL. See [discussions 28932](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/28932#discussioncomment-7989506)

> ### REST API - /projects - Unable to manage projects via REST endpoints
>
> Since the Project (classic) is deprecation, I have unable to manage projects using the GitHub API (https://api.github.com/projects) due to either; Authentication failure, 404, or empty response data.
>
> you can't even query projects through orgs anymore through
> [https://api.github.com/orgs/{org}/projects](https://api.github.com/orgs/%7Borg%7D/projects)
> You just get an empty array back. Shame.

---

As noted in "[REST API / Projects (classic)](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/projects/projects?apiVersion=2022-11-28)":

> - These endpoints only interact with projects (classic). To manage Projects, use the GraphQL API. For more information, see "[Using the API to manage Projects](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/planning-and-tracking-with-projects/automating-your-project/using-the-api-to-manage-projects)"
> - To create a new classic project, the organization, user, or repository must already have at least one classic project.
>
> The REST API to manage projects (classic) only supports authentication using a personal access token (classic). For more information, see "[Managing your personal access tokens](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)"

Comment: Tried it again. New Token -> PAT (classic) - all scopes: Doesn't work. Same results.
It also can not be the **rate limit**, because I waited more than a day to try again.

Comment: Looks like there is only one api version: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/about-the-rest-api/api-versions?apiVersion=2022-11-28#supported-api-versions

Comment: @ihaveaquestion Can you test with curl? `curl -H "Authorization: token YOUR_PAT" -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" https://api.github.com/orgs/propromo-software/projects`

Comment: Forgot to say that. Tested with curl too.

Comment: @ihaveaquestion OK, so the issue is not limited to Bruno.

Comment: Tried my second account. same results.

Comment: Maybe it only works using a GithubApp.

Comment: @ihaveaquestion or the [GitHub CLI gh](https://cli.github.com/)?

Comment: Same result. `gh: Must have admin rights to Repository. (HTTP 403)`

Comment: Does it work for you? Can you send requests to these endpoints?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256644/discussion-between-vonc-and-ihaveaquestion).